# Get target Object in Aspect and call another method on target object

Tags: java, aspectj

I want to write an aspect on a method pointcut, and in the aspect I want to call another method using the object on which pointcut method is called.

Something like this:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.mypackage.Notify(getC))")
public void notifyPointCut() {
}

@AfterReturning(value = "notifyPointCut(getC)", argNames = "joinPoint") 
public void notifyChange (JoinPoint joinPoint) {
  Object targetObject  = joinPoint.getTarget();
  C cField = targetObject.invokeMethod("getC");
  notifier.sendUpdate(cField);
}
```

I want to get the object on which joinPoint method is called and make another method call on that object (method name that is passed in the annotation)

My use case is to get some fields of the object, these fields are created or updated by joinPoint method. Once joinPoint method returns, I want to get those fields in the aspect and send a notification on the field value.

I am not sure if I am complicating aspect usage too much as I could not find such a usage anywhere on searching.

Comment: I would cast the value returned by `joinPoint.getTarget()` to your expected type. And then just call `targetObject.getC()`

Comment: But I am unaware about the expected type. Is there any way to invoke method without casting

Comment: But If that type doesn't declare `getC()` method you will get an exception. If you are sure that the type declares this method, then extract it to an interface and cast `joinPoint.getTarget();` to that interface instead of concrete class.

Comment: I think the pointcut syntax is wrong. What is `(getC)` inside `@annotation(com.mypackage.Notify(getC))` and inside `otifyPointCut(getC)` supposed to mean anyway? This should not even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to invoke the method. I need to get the method and invoke it, then I do not need to do casting for the class.

```
Object targetObject  = joinPoint.getTarget();
Method m = targetObject.getMethod("getC");
m.invoke(targetObject);
```

Comment: This is ugly and certainly not a stable solution. Because of reflection it is also error-prone and slow. User *bigdestroyer* is right, if you know that the target type has a certain method, you should also know the type itself or maybe a common super type or super interface. The way you do it now is just bad design.